# Combine hash properties from array of hashes

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, object

I'm parsing an excel spreadsheet and trying to combine data rows by id across tables and files.  This is a condensed, simplified version of what I have.  With a PHP/JS background, I prefer conceptualizing hashes as objects, so %aoo means array of objects instead of array of hashes...

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.10.0;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;
use Data::Dumper;

# Array of objects
# Each object is a row from a table
my $aoo1 = [
    {
        "id"    => 1,
        "name"  => "Dan",
        "team"  => "red"
    },
    {
        "id"    => 2,
        "name"  => "Arnold",
        "team"  => "red"
    },
    {
        "id"    => 3,
        "name"  => "Kristen",
        "team"  => "red"
    }
];
my @aoo2 = (
    {
        "id"    => 1,
        "position"  => "web developer",
    },
    {
        "id"    => 2,
        "position"  => "CEO",
    },
    {
        "id"    => 3,
        "position"  => "Secretary",
    }
);
my @aoo3 = (
    {
        "id"    => 1,
        "tenure"  => "1yr",
    },
    {
        "id"    => 2,
        "tenure"  => "25yr",
    },
    {
        "id"    => 3,
        "tenure"  => "5yr",
    }
);

# object of arrays
# each property is a table name from spreadsheet
my %ooa;
%ooa = (
    "People List" => $aoo1,
    "Position List" => \@aoo2,
    "Tenure List" => \@aoo3
);

# dd \%ooa;

while (my ($list_name, $aoo) = each %ooa)
{
    # $aoo reftype is array | [ %object, %object, %object ]
    # Do something to look into other objects for same id...
}
```

I want to be able to create a new object for each unique row in the file, so I can filter the values and then write it to a CSV file.

Ex. of the end result

```
%complete_row = (
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Dan',
    'team' => 'red',
    'position => 'Web Dev',
    'tenure' => '1yr'
);
```

Comment: Your data structures are wrong. You want a single hash where the keys are IDs and the values are hashes (hash references) with all the properties for that ID.

Comment: @MattJacob So something like %object_of_objects1 = ( 1 => { 'name' => 'Dan',}), %object_of_objects2 = (2 => { 'position' => 'Web Dev'}), etc?

Comment: No. Stop thinking in terms of parallel data structures. A *single* hash: `{ 1 => { name => ‘John’, title => ‘CEO’ }, 2 => { name => ‘Jane’, title => ‘CFO’ }, 3 => ... }`

Comment: @MattJacob That's what I want as the end result, but I am getting data from spreadsheets, so that's why the data is separated the way it is.  I need to be able to parse a single table in a file, multiple tables in a single file, or that across multiple files.  That is why I am doing it the way I am.  I'm thinking a recursive hash merging function would do what I would want.

Comment: Ok, so... loops?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work:

```
my %newHash;
foreach my $arrRef(map {$ooa{$_}} keys %ooa) { #reading all values of ooa hash, each value is an array ref
    foreach my $hashRef(@$arrRef) { #reading each array element, each array element is a hash ref 
        foreach my $key(keys %{$hashRef}) { #reading all keys of each internal hash
            $newHash{$hashRef->{'id'}}{$key} = $hashRef->{$key}; #building new hash of hashes with id as key and value as hash ref
        }
    }
}
my @newArray = map {$newHash{$_}} keys %newHash; #converting hash of hashes into array of hashes
```

Comment: So the outer foreach manually sets all the arrays of hashes, how would I modify it to work with an object with a varying number of arrays?

Comment: I updated my answer so you need only set ooa hash now.

Comment: Could you explain what's happening in the loop process a little bit?

Comment: Added some comments. Let me know if you need more explanation of some particular piece.

Answer (score 0):

Put the 2nd and 3rd arrays into hashes mapping ID to the hash.  Then loop through the people and use the ID to get the data from position and tenure hashes.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $people = [
    {
        id    => 1,
        name  => "Dan",
        team  => "red"
    },
    {
        id    => 2,
        name  => "Arnold",
        team  => "red"
    },
    {
        id    => 3,
        name  => "Kristen",
        team  => "red"
    }
];

my $positions = [
    {
        id => 1,
        position => "web developer",
    },
    {
        id => 2,
        position => "CEO",
    },
    {
        id => 3,
        position => "Secretary",
    }
];

my $tenures = [
    {
        id => 1,
        tenure => "1yr",
    },
    {
        id => 2,
        tenure => "25yr",
    },
    {
        id => 3,
        tenure => "5yr",
    }
];

# hash each by ID
my %position_hash = map { $_->{id} => $_ } @$positions;
my %tenure_hash   = map { $_->{id} => $_ } @$tenures;

# combine
my $complete = [];
foreach my $person (@$people) {
    my $id = $person->{id};
    my $complete_row = {
        %$person,
        position => $position_hash{$id}->{position},
        tenure => $tenure_hash{$id}->{tenure},
    };
    push @$complete, $complete_row
}
print "complete = " . Dumper($complete);
```

Comment: That works when the number of objects is know, but how would I map the ids dynamically depending on the number of sheets per workbook?  Say, $book = [ 'sheet1' => %object1, 'sheet2' => %object2' ] ?